# Design for scientific data. Data table with hundreds of columns or data table with a generic value column and hundreds of rows (EAV)?

Tags: database-design, schema, eav

I am trying to improve the data storage in biomedical science lab where I recently started working. The existing workflow is atrocious, involving many differently formatted Excel sheets that all get aggregated through a process of copy-paste and buggy macros.

My intent is to create a simple python script which aggregates all of the data for an experiment into an SQLite database and then produces the requisite CSV/XLSX output.

My issue is that for a single trial of our experiment, we end up with about 100 variables recorded at about 10 different time points. My initial impulse was to create a `value` and `variable` table:

```
CREATE TABLE value (val_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
                    value TEXT, 
                    var_id INTEGER,
                    event_id INTEGER,
                    exp_id INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (var_id) REFERENCES variable(var_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES event(event_id),
                    FOREIGN KEY (exp_id) REFERENCES experiemnt(exp_id)
);

CREATE TABLE variable (var_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                      var_name TEXT,
                       var_type TEXT
);

value:
val_id | value | var_id | ...
0      | 10    | 0
1      | "ROSC"| 5

variable:
var_id | var_name | var_type
0      | Pressure | DECIMAL
...
5      | Outcome  | TEXT
```

But this feels wrong and I have a hunch at the "proper" way to do this is to have a single data table with the hundreds of columns that would otherwise be described in the `variable` table since this would make it easier to do type checking (yes, I know SQLite doesn't do this, but in principle).

Any insight into how to tackle this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is the EAV (Entity Attribute Value) model which most database professionals would run a mile from. It's also sarcastically called the OTLT (One True Lookup Table) and is a classic novice mistake. Your hunch is correct!

[Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/) (and [here](https://books.google.ie/books?id=BtCOgrpzbz4C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=celko%20muck&source=bl&ots=W9LTsN8KTz&sig=6iqqRfdf-49n1pcNKi8kqfBCKzU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hA6HVdrlNdCU7QaCm4GoBQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=celko%20muck&f=false)) is the opinion of Joe Celko (a veteran SQL programmer who is/was a member of the SQL standards committee.  The fact that he titles his article with the phrase "EAV of destruction" should give you a clue :-).  Celko also calls this the Massively Unified Code Key.

It's no coincidence that the acronym is MUCK! :-)

Storing data in this way destroys many of the advantages of relational databases such as DRI (Declarative Referential Integrity), CHECK constraints and DEFAULT values.

Please create a table with 100 fields and 10 rows - if that's what your data requires, then do it. Perhaps a couple of other fields with experiment ID, datetime and experimenter_id would also be useful? That way you can perform analyses over given periods, various other aggregates - basically slice and dice **all** of your data.

< Personal opinion > If you haven't chosen your database yet and are happy to use F/LOSS, then may I recommend PostgreSQL - it's SQL dialect is by far the richest of the Open Source databases (I have no connection to the project). Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2762020/470530) for how to enforce datatypes in SQLite, but PostgreSQL offers more than SQLite - it's multi-user for example and no need to jump through hoops to enforce datatypes.< / Personal opinion >

[EDIT1]

Just one further remark, and for completeness, there is only one significant system out there that makes use of the EAV model - and that's Magento ([1](http://magento.com/), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento)). Its principal niche is the fashion industry where the EAV model may be suitable for sparse tables (fashion items tend to be available in a myriad of colours, syles, sizes...). It is popular ([1](http://blog.aheadworks.com/2014/10/e-commerce-platforms-share-investigation-october-2014/), [2](http://www.brainsins.com/en/blog/magento-most-popular-ecommerce-cms/3619)), but then so is MySQL which is inferior in many ways to PostgreSQL, Firebird and (multi-user capability aside) SQLite.