# Performance impact of NOT using a foreign key (many dedicated 1:many key-key tables vs non-fk generic key-key table)

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, join, polymorphic-associations

We're using a lot of association tables to manage 1:many relationships among a variety of different objects in our system.

To illustrate the question, two examples would be:

1. `users`, `events`, `ass_users_events`.  The `ass_users_events` would contain only the `User_ID` and `Event_ID` columns, both with foreign key relationships.
2. `projects`, `tasks`, `ass_projects_tasks`.  The `ass_projects_tasks` would contain only the `Project_ID` and `Task_ID` columns, both with foreign key relationships.

*NB1: Every object table actually uses a combination of an Auto-Incrementing Integer Primary Key, plus a UUID column with a unique index which is the actual record ID. For the purpose of this question, we're using only UUID's so there is no chance of collision.*

*NB2: The reason we use this format rather than a straight Foreign Key column/index is that the reality is much more complex than this example, there are many different joins to many different tables and we don't want the ORM doing a lot of unnecessary work every time a record is loaded.*

The problem is we're starting to create these associational tables for pretty much every new object type in the system for many of the other existing objects in the system and in the long run this doesn't seem sustainable, we'll end up with hundreds of association types.

A potential solution we're considering is getting rid of ALL of the current associational tables and instead creating one table with the following structure: `obj_1_id`, `obj_1_type`, `obj_2_id`, `obj_2_type`.  Every column would be indexed, likely as composite indexes (i.e. `INDEX object_1 (obj_1_type,obj_1_id)` and `INDEX object_2 (obj_2_type,obj_2_id)`).

The examples above in the ass tables would become: `abc,user,123,event`, and `def,project,456,task`.

This solution gives us the flexibility to build as many relationship types as we want between different objects, and there's ample indexing on the ass table to remain performant.  My question is **is there a downside to using indexing only during joins, vs having defined foreign key relationships in smaller tables, but potentially hundreds of them?**

---

**EDIT:**  I think there are some misconceptions below so this might clear up a couple things:

1. I use polymorphic object structures, but every object is stored in it's own table, i.e. user, product, category, event, etc.
2. As far as the proposed ass table, it will only have 4 functional fields, with very straightforward datatypes (plus one `ai_col` as primary).  The datatypes would be varchar(10) for the `type` cols and CHAR(32) / BINARY(16) for the id's.  SELECT's will only ever have one join, to the ass table, i.e.

   `SELECT event.*  FROM event INNER JOIN ass ON ass.obj_1_type = 'event' AND ass.Object_ID_1 = event.Event_ID AND ass.obj_2_type='location'`

there's no reason I would ever ask for two of these objects at once, I would only be filtering results from one table by existence of ass links.

1. UUID's are the real Unique ID's here, but every table uses `ai_col` which is an INNODB construct for increasing the performance of their clustered index.
2. This is a read heavy environment, I'm not near as concerned with insert/delete performance.
3. We use handlersocket for simple read AND write queries removing the SQL overhead.
4. The integrity of this table is acceptable at *Eventually Consistent* in this specific use case.

---

**EDIT 2:** To make this crystal clear, here's the why...  if I have 200 objects each in their own tables, that I want to be able to link in all possible ways, I would either have to have 199 foreign key relationships in each object table, or I would have to create 40,000 tables with all the possible combinations and then all the business logic to go with that. Using a the method we're considering, there's one table and I have RI taken care of at the application level, which I indicated is ok at eventually consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance impact of not using a foreign key. A foreign key constraint simply enforces referential integrity by constraining the values that can be inserted into the foreign key column (s).

If you are using UUIDS as identifiers, why do you need the type columns in the association table?

As you mention modelling this in the traditional manner would result in a large number of tables. Deleting, for example, a user would result in the RDBMS checking each foreign key constraint to ensure non are violated, which could take some time! With your proposed approach the RDBMS would have no foreign key constraints to check and the user would be deleted quicker. So you actually get better performance deleting objects. As you noted you'll have to have a background job that makes the association table eventually consistent. Regarding this, you could consider keeping a log of deleted objects and replaying it against the associations table. This would be better performing than carrying out a existence check on each row to see if the referenced objects still exist.

I've used this approach for several years now to allow anything to relate to anything else and haven't encountered any issues.

Comment: The type column allows for the composite index and is purely for efficiency, without it, the entire table would be scanned for any linked records, and I wouldn't be able to tell without a second join if that link was the right object type or not.  With the type as the first part of the composite index, I can filter first by object type without the need of a second join.  Good to know I'm not crazy and this approach has real world application though, thanks.

Comment: *"There is no performance impact of not using a foreign key."* Is this claim a general one or is referring to MySQL only?

Comment: Different RDBMS products differ wildly in the cost of checking for orphaned references when something is deleted.  Don't use the results obtained with one product to predict the behavior of other products.

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me that you are considering the EAV (Entity Attribute Value) model, i.e. wedging every object into a single table, rather than having different tables for different objects. EAV is generally considered an [antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

It can be known as an Open and/or flexible Schema. It is also known (sarcastically) as the OTLT (One True Lookup Table), (even more sarcastically) as MUCK (Massively Unified Code Key - [Joe Celko](http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.ie/2006/06/changing-columns-of-select-statement.html)) and perhaps best of all (I only just found this) as DEMONS (Diabolically Enticing Method Of iNformation Storage - adapted from [Mike Smithers](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/)).

It is interesting to note that Celko (who was a member of the ANSI/ISO SQL committee which determines/ed the SQL standard) said (see reference) about the programmer who had written such a system that the questioner should "Find the moron that did this to you and **kill him**".

See the Smithers' post (and and Celko's writings [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/avoiding-the-eav-of-destruction/) and [here](https://books.google.ie/books?id=BtCOgrpzbz4C&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=celko%20muck&source=bl&ots=W9LTsN8KTz&sig=6iqqRfdf-49n1pcNKi8kqfBCKzU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hA6HVdrlNdCU7QaCm4GoBQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=celko%20muck&f=false)) about the difficulties of writing queries against EAV schemas. It's no coincidence that Celko titles his first article "Avoiding the EAV of Destruction". Take a look [here](http://karwin.blogspot.ie/2009/05/eav-fail.html) for an absolutely hilarious visual analogy of the EAV system from Bill Karwin - a highly respected SQL guru and author of a book "[SQL Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934356557)".

You mention "**having defined foreign key relationships in smaller tables, but potentially hundreds of them**". Modern RDBMSs can cope with hundreds of tables and FK relationships between them and unless you have **VERY** strong reasons (with proven testing behind your argument), then stick with traditional relational principles.

To directly **answer your question**, in all likelihood, the complexity of the queries that you will need to use to obtain data results from an EAV system will have **FAR** more of a negative performance impact than a system with many tables with clear, properly defined FK relationships using INT(11) foreign keys or even UUIDs.

Another point about performance - use of an EAV system will force you to use inappropriate datatypes and this will seriously interfere with your RDBMSs query optimiser's ability to (err...) optimise the queries. Under these EAV systems, many values are (again inappropriately) stored as strings and converted on-the-fly, which is both time-consuming and, again, confusing for the optimiser - **not recommended**.

From my accepted answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104697/34007) and for completeness and honesty, just one further remark. There is only one significant system out there that makes use of the EAV model - and that's Magento ([1](http://magento.com/), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magento)). Its principal niche is the fashion industry where the EAV model **may** be suitable for sparse tables (fashion items tend to be available in a myriad of colours, syles, sizes...). It is popular ([1](http://blog.aheadworks.com/2014/10/e-commerce-platforms-share-investigation-october-2014/), [2](http://www.brainsins.com/en/blog/magento-most-popular-ecommerce-cms/3619)), but then so is MySQL which is inferior in many ways to PostgreSQL, Firebird and (multi-user capability aside) SQLite.

I also noticed this in the comments

> but I never rely entirely on the DB's RI, I generally do it at the
>   application layer falling back on RI as a backup. I've considered
>   using a maint task that runs occasionally to remove orphaned records
>   to shore that up as well.

This is nothing short of madness.

The RI (Referential Integrity) capabilities of MySQL (and other RDBMSs) have been tested by literally **MILLIONS** of users. If you set up a proper PK-FK relationship between two of your tables, then the chances of this failing are virtually NIL! You'd be **far** better off using your time and effort to focus on other areas of your application than ensuring proper RI - unless you've committed the unpardonable sin of implementing RI in the app rather than using the capabilities of the RDBMS. See Jonathan Lewis' disaster no.2 in my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74467/34007). Lewis wrote [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590596366), so he knows a thing or two about databases.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30739/discussion-on-answer-by-verace-performance-impact-of-not-using-a-foreign-key-ma).

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight

Right now a join looks like this

```
select users.*, event.* 
  from users 
  join ass_users_events 
    on ass_users_event.userID = users.ID 
  join event 
    on event.ID = ass_users_events.eventID
```

So what would your join look like?

```
select users.*, event.* 
  from users 
  join ass 
    on ass.obj_1_id = users.ID 
   and ass.obj_1_type = 'user' 
   and ass.obj_2_type = 'event'
  join event 
    on event.ID = ass.obj_2_id
```

If so I am not seeing the value here
That is a messy join to avoid an ass_users_events table
And you lose declarative referential integrity

How is the first causing the ORM to do unnecessary work?

Dedicated tables are performant and sustainable

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30738/discussion-on-answer-by-frisbee-performance-impact-of-not-using-a-foreign-key-m).